# Azure Automation: How to start Azure Runbook from Hybrid Runbook - without another authentication?

Tags: azure, azure-automation

I have a working Azure Automation Hybrid Runbook Worker that is successfully executing runbooks. From one such Hybrid runbook I need to pass a result on to another runbook that must run on Azure, not on the Hybrid Worker.

After doing some research it seems that I have to use the `Start-AzAutomationRunbook` cmdlet to start the Azure runbook - which requires a `Connect-AzAccount` before, which [means additional authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-child-runbooks#example-1):

> To use Start-AzAutomationRunbook, the script must authenticate to your
> Azure subscription.

But this seems overly complicated. Is there a less complex way to chain Azure and Hybrid runbooks? Without having to explicitly authenticate again? Overall, the runbooks are located in the same Automation account right next to each other.

Comment: Hi, Yes as explained [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-child-runbooks), you could start a child runbook using Start-AzAutomationRunbook cmdlet which requires you to first connect using Connect-AzAccount. But in the same referred document, we can invoke a child runbook using inline execution i.e., it works if all runbooks in the same Automation account are available to all others. I haven't tried it by having parent runbook executing in HRW and then having a child runbook to be executed in Azure env. so you may try out this inline execution to see if it works.

Comment: @KrishnaG-MSFT On the HRW I called the child runbook as outlined in the [inline example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-child-runbooks#example) using the `.\PS-ChildRunbook.ps1` syntax. This runs the runbook on the HRW as well. But I want it to execute on Azure. I guess this sentence here is the key for inline execution: _When you invoke a runbook inline, it runs in the same job as the parent runbook._ - meaning when calling form the HRW the child will also run on the HRW. This currently leaves the `Start-AzAutomationRunbook` as only option.